# Android Studio cannot install app on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-emulator

When I click run, gradle will finish with 0 errors. However, the install gets stuck in an infinite loop. My compile sdk version is 29, and my min sdk version was 21, was I tried changing my min sdk version to 29 but it still did not work.

Debugger says SHELL_UNRESPONSIVE

I have sdk version 30 installed for my emulator, and it worked fine up to now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio and/or the adb process sometimes get stuck. Keep the emulator open, while fully closing and then restarting Android Studio. If this doesn't work, check your task manager and also shut down any `adb` process when you shut down Android Studio.